# Display text inside a textfield with dynamic asp value

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

How can I write this so the text shows in the text field (search bar) during the page load?

`<input type="text" id="addressInput" value="<%=addressStr%>" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Search a location here';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Search a location here')this.value='';" />`

At the moment the text only shows when you click in the textfield.

Comment: Just to clarify, ASP or ASP.NET?

Comment: Thanks drachenstern, I will look into your suggestion below. It is for .asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@detonate: You could just add some of the same logic to the ASP value so it'll show `Search a location here` if `addressStr` is blank:

```
<input type="text" id="addressInput" value="<% If addressStr = "" Then Response.Write "Search a location here" End If %>" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Search a location here';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Search a location here')this.value='';" />
```

Comment: Thanks stealthyningja, this is exactly what I tried to achieve and needed!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're trying to setup a watermark for a textbox, is that correct?

I'm going to refer you to a basic example of textbox watermarking that should be able to give you an example and give everyone a bit of a common codebase for discussion, since you didn't include a lot of code in your post: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WatermarkTextBox.aspx

In it, I'll reference one of his codeblocks, that is similar to the one you posted:

```
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserId" runat="server" 
        onfocus="Focus(this.id,'User ID')"
        onblur="Blur(this.id,'User ID')" 
        Width="126px" CssClass="WaterMarkedTextBox">User ID</asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

While I realize he used ASP.NET instead of ASP, I wanted to draw attention to the fact that he put `<textbox>text</textbox>` so that you could see part of the answer to the question you directly asked above.

---

**EDIT:** Let me try this again: You would have something like this:

```
<textbox attributes="" methods="" > 
  <%=addressStr%> 
</textbox>
```

---

Hopefully tho, the whole example given on that page will help you. Feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: Looking for a text solution but if I can't figure it out, this might just do the trick!